# Change parent element style with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have next html setup:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <a href="#" class="three">Click</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to change background color for element with class ***.one*** when I click on element ***.three*** with jQuery.

This is what I was trying to use:

```
$(function(){
    $('.three')(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    })
});
```

Here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/a7unbs2p/

I was searching for solution here on SO but wasn't able to find it fast enough (probably I didn't look good enough :/).

Thank you.

Comment: Whoa, thank you @adeneo !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use `.click()` or `.on('click')` .. and you can use `.closest()` as well instead of using `parent()` twice

```
$(function(){
    $('.three').on('click',function(){
        $(this).closest('.one').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. @adeneo was a bit faster with his comment :) Thank you both.

Comment: What If I have more elements with class name .two and I ALSO want to change background for all .two elements (same setup, and only first element .two have element. three inside of it)? Do you have idea maybe?

Comment: @DejanMunjiza Is this what you looking for?? https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/a7unbs2p/6/  .. I really can't got your point .. may be you can explain it better by saying ( I need when I click on ... I need .... to change ...)  maybe this way I can understand what you want

Comment: yes. That's it. Absolute beginner with jQuery so this was a great help.

Comment: @DejanMunjiza 1st you're totally welcome .. 2nd if you need to learn about jquery I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810 its very very simplest and easiest tutorials be helpful for you .. 3d: Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add Click event at your code. First add jquery.min.js then add the script. You can do like this -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(".three").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().parent().css("background","red");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: $('.three').parents('#somedive').css('prop','value')

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a descedant of the element, you can use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) which travels up until the selector is found.

Additionally, You can use the CSS syntax inside of the CSS method (`background-color` instead of `backgroundColor`).

```
$('.three').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('.one').css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

Comment: What if I have more elements with the same class? For e.g if with this setup I have 3 elements with .two class name, and I want to change background (for e.g) for all 3 elements at once?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The `.two` class isn't involved in this example; it's basically skipped.  Can you update your question and I'll update my answer?

Comment: Sorry, lets try this way. I want to change background for all elements with class ".row" in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/a7unbs2p/1/

Comment: `$(this).parents('.row').siblings().addBack().css('background-color', 'red');`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so, little addition to higher answer:

```
$(function(){
    $('.three').on('click',function(){
        $(this).closest('.one').css('background-color', 'red');
    })
});
```

Css doesn't have property with name backgroundColor

Comment: Unlike CSS's background-color, you have to write backgroundColor since Javascript interprets the hyphen as a subtraction operation.

Comment: Thanks I don't know that fact!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
$('.three').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('.one').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
})
```

Comment: And what is the different between your answer and may answer??

Comment: No difference, but is it so that I cant come up with similar solution?